# iOS: Is there a way to delete specific files securely from the file system?

Tags: ios, security, encryption

I am writing an application for iOS and a requirement I have been given is to remove files securely from the file system that may be given to my app from other applications (think 'Open in...').  These files are placed in a temp folder accessible to my app, but I'd like to securely delete these files once I have encrypted them in my own documents folder via the standard protection APIs.  Any idea how to do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean 'securely'? I suppose you could write `0`'s over them a few times and then delete the files if you are paranoid, although with flash memory is that really necessary?

Comment: @Justin Ethier - To render the file irrecoverable if the device were compromised.

Comment: Securely deleting files on a flash memory is more difficult than it seems - as a single flash cell can only be written a certain number of times, written data gets randomly distributed over the entire disk (wear levelling). This is why it is possible that you overwrite a file multiple times with `0`'s and it is still recoverable.

Comment: As far as I know, anyone who actually wants secure deletion uses physical destruction. For hard disks, overwriting the whole disk with random data a few times is usually good enough (except if it remapped a bad sector...). For flash devices, data may be recoverable even if you overwrite the *whole drive* a few times.

Comment: Here’s a link to an interesting paper about secure file removal on SSDs: http://www.usenix.org/events/fast11/tech/full_papers/Wei.pdf

Comment: @tc: Certainly that is true given the standard C/POSIX file APIs, but that doesn't mean the OS/driver cannot provide a way to securely delete them. (Destroying the phone is not really an option.)

Comment: @Joe: I'd still be *very* skeptical of anything offering single-file secure deletion on a wear-levelling flash device (i.e. all of them); the only sensible way I can think of is for the flash controller to set the "old" copy of a block to all-ones on overwrite (instead of doing a wear-causing erase). However, the NSFileManager docs say that you need to set the file encryption attribute *before* doing any writes, so I suspect there is no "secure delete" (and even then, anyone with the passcode can recover erased files, but presumably that's less of a problem?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quotes from the [paper](http://www.usenix.org/events/fast11/tech/full_papers/Wei.pdf) linked to by Bavarious:

> We found that none of the available software techniques for sanitizing individual files were effective.
>
> Overall, we conclude that the increased complexity of SSDs relative to hard drives requires that SSDs provide verifiable sanitization operations.

I'm not sure the flash memory in iPhones supports these operations, but if they do I'm pretty sure that Apple will have to make them available through their API and I haven't found anything in the API for this.

So basically it doesn't seem to be possible. Perhaps you could file a bug report with Apple and ask them to fix something like this.

I think you're better of looking into the possibility to encrypt the file before saving it.